# How to implement a minium average return in the Python scipy.optimize.minimize function for portfolio allocation

Tags: python, scipy-optimize, portfolio, scipy-optimize-minimize

I try to optimize a portfolio weight of 4 assets with given Covariance Matrix, expected return and weight array. I want to find the optimal allocation (reduce variance) given three constrains:

1. Sum of weight must be equal to 1
2. Weight of single asset can't be negative
3. The expected return of the portfolio must have be at least 6%

I already implemented the 1st and 2nd one but struggle to implement the 3rd one. Here is the code

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from scipy.optimize import LinearConstraint
from scipy.optimize import Bounds

e = np.array([0.06, 0.053, 0.07, 0.08])

V = np.array([[0.0224, 0.0184, 0.025, 0.0288],
[0.0184, 0.0223, 0.0275, 0.0299],
[0.025, 0.0275, 0.0403, 0.0438],
[0.0288, 0.0299, 0.0438, 0.0515]])

w = np.array([0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25])

w. T @ e
w. T @ V @ w

def f(w, V):
    return w.T @ V @ w

sum_weights = LinearConstraint ([1, 1, 1, 1,], [1], [1])
bounds = Bounds([0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1])


res = minimize(f, w, args = V, method='trust-constr', constraints=[sum_weights], bounds=bounds)
res
```

I modelled the problem already in excel and should get a variance of ~2,217% and a std.dev of ~14,89%

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what part you're struggling with. Assuming that your array `e` is the expected asset returns, you need to solve the following QP:

```
min  w.T @ V @ w   

s.t. 

1^T @ w    = 1
e^T @ w   >= 0.06
      w   >= 0
```

Note that the first two constraints are equivalent to

```
1    <= 1^T @ w   <= 1
0.06 <= e^T @ w   <= ∞
```

Therefore, you can pass both by one LinearConstraint instance:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize, Bounds, LinearConstraint

e = np.array([0.06, 0.053, 0.07, 0.08])

V = np.array([[0.0224, 0.0184, 0.025, 0.0288],
[0.0184, 0.0223, 0.0275, 0.0299],
[0.025, 0.0275, 0.0403, 0.0438],
[0.0288, 0.0299, 0.0438, 0.0515]])

w0 = np.array([0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25])

def objective(w):
    return w.T @ V @ w

A = np.block([[np.ones(e.size)], [e]])
cons = LinearConstraint(A, lb = np.array([1, 0.06]), ub = np.array([1, np.inf]))

res = minimize(objective, x0=w0, method='trust-constr', bounds=Bounds(lb=0), constraints=cons)
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your help! But somehow in this code the sum of the weights isnt equal to 1. Its 1.0000000000000047 in this case. Why this problem occurs?

Comment: `print(res.x.sum())` gives 1.0 ....